# Using THE in Sentences

Tags: grammar, syntactic-analysis

When there is a phrase like "the page of the book," is it correct to put both the in the sentence? What are the rules in general? What if we had more OF in the sentence? e.g. "the room of the department of the organization"

Comment: Yes, it is correct to say "the page of the book", but only if what you actually want to say is "the page of the book". If instead you really mean *a* page of *a* book, *the* page of *a* book, or *a* page of *the* book, then using two *thes* would be incorrect.

Comment: The rule for using "the" vs "a" is simple and does not change depending on how many other times "the" or "a" is used in a sentence.  In your examples, it would never be correct to remove "the" and not replace it with "a".  For example, "The room of department of organisation" is simply wrong.